# How to calculate next, previous business day in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to calculate next and previous business days in Rails?

Comment: Are holidays considered a business day? Are the business days just M-F?

Comment: M-F only(holidays considered business days).
but if you can give me to filter holidays that will be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? You should add your code attempts in your question.

Comment: Calculating holiday days is pretty complicated, you'll need to do it (probably) by country.  If this is a finance app you'll need to do it per exchange.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I understand, this is what you are looking for? (tested it)

```
require 'date'
def next_business_day(date)
  skip_weekends(date, 1)
end    

def previous_business_day(date)
  skip_weekends(date, -1)
end

def skip_weekends(date, inc = 1)
  date += inc
  while date.wday == 0 || date.wday == 6
    date += inc
  end   
  date
end
```

You can test it as follows:

```
begin
  t = Date.new(2009,9,11) #Friday, today
  puts "Today: #{Date::DAYNAMES[t.wday]} #{Date::MONTHNAMES[t.mon]} #{t.day}"
  nextday = next_business_day(t)
  puts "Next B-day: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[nextday.mon]} #{nextday.day}"
  previousday = previous_business_day(nextday)
  puts "back to previous: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[previousday.mon]} #{previousday.day}"
  yesterday = previous_business_day(previousday)
  puts "yesterday: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[yesterday.mon]} #{yesterday.day}"  
end
```

Comment: If your date in question is a Sunday, the above doesn't work, and if you try increment 7 days from the sunday, it sticks in an infinite loop.

Comment: @DavidNorth, it works fine. The next business day after Sunday can reasonably be considered to be Monday. And it seems you are only supposed to pass 1 or -1 to skip_weekends, which is just a helper for the other two methods. (Although it would be better if it checked for invalid arguments instead of going into an infinite loop.)

Comment: I passed Time object as the argument and was left wondering how it could take more than 1 sec to get to the result. I think it would be better to be explicit by doing `date += inc.day`

Comment: I think in your `skip_weekends` method `date.wday % 7` is unnecessary, `date.wday` is always between `0..6`. So it could be like `while [6, 0].include?(date.wday) do`

Comment: @rkallensee or you could use `date.wday % 6 == 0`. Less computation but YAGNI, and harder for comprehension

Answer (score 15):

```
date = Date.today
date.next_weekday
date.prev_weekday
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that we don't have it in plain Ruby :(

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

With the [holidays-gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/holidays) you can also check, if there is a public holiday. If you do so, you must define the region you need.
The holidays-gem allows also to use subregions (e.g. us-va...)

An example code with German (de) and US-american (us) holidays.

```
require 'holidays'
require 'holidays/us'
require 'holidays/de'
require 'holidays/core_extensions/date'
class Date
  include Holidays::CoreExtensions::Date #provide Date#holiday?

  def next_business_day(region=:any)
    skip_weekends_and_holidays(1,region)
  end    

  def previous_business_day(region=:any)
    skip_weekends_and_holidays(-1,region)
  end

  def skip_weekends_and_holidays(inc, region = :any)
    date = self + inc
    while (date.wday == 6 or date.holiday?(region) ) do
      date += inc
    end   
    date
  end
end
```

Get attention: `skip_weekends_and_holidays` does not increment business days. If you increment 5 days from a Monday, you end on a Monday (unless this Monday is no holiday). If there was a holiday during the 5 days, there is additional increment.

Some test code:

```
[
  Date.new(2012,6,8), #Friday
  Date.new(2012,6,10), #Monday
  Date.new(2012,6,9), #Sunday
  Date.new(2012,12,24), #Christmas eve
  Date.new(2012,12,26), #After Christmas 
].each{|t|
  %w{us de}.each{|region|
    puts "====#{region}======"
    puts "Today: #{Date::DAYNAMES[t.wday]} #{Date::MONTHNAMES[t.mon]} #{t.day}"
    nextday = t.next_business_day(region)
    puts "Next B-day: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[nextday.mon]} #{nextday.day} - #{Date::DAYNAMES[nextday.wday]}"
    previousday = t.previous_business_day(region)
    puts "Previous B-day: #{Date::MONTHNAMES[previousday.mon]} #{previousday.day} - #{Date::DAYNAMES[previousday.wday]}"
  }
```

An extract from result (christmas eve):

```
====us======
Today: Monday December 24
Next B-day: December 26 - Wednesday
Previous B-day: December 23 - Sunday
```

Germany has two free days (25+26.12):

```
====de======
Today: Monday December 24
Next B-day: December 27 - Thursday
Previous B-day: December 23 - Sunday
```

---

Update: I made another version to determine multiple business days:

```
require 'holidays'
require 'holidays/us'
require 'holidays/core_extensions/date'
#~ require 'holidays/de'
class Date
  include Holidays::CoreExtensions::Date #provide Date#holiday?
  def next_business_day(region=:any)
    next_business_days(1,region)
  end    

  def next_business_days(inc, region=:any)
    date = self
    inc.times{
      date = date.next
      while (date.wday == 6 or date.holiday?(region) ) do
        date = date.next
      end
    }
    date
  end    

  def previous_business_day(region=:any)
    previous_business_days(1,region)
  end

  def previous_business_days(inc, region=:any)
    date = self
    inc.times{
      date = date.prev_day
      while (date.wday == 6 or date.holiday?(region) ) do
        date = date.prev_day
      end
    }
    date
  end    


end
```

My test code:

```
require 'test/unit'
class BDay_Test < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_2012_06_08_us()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 8)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 10), date.next_business_day('us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  7), date.previous_business_day('us'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 17), date.next_business_days(7, 'us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 05, 31), date.previous_business_day(7, 'us'))
  end
  def test_2012_06_08_de()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 8)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 10), date.next_business_day('de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  7), date.previous_business_day('de'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 17), date.next_business_days(7, 'de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 05, 31), date.previous_business_day(7, 'de'))
  end
  def test_2012_06_10_us()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 10)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 11), date.next_business_day('us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  8), date.previous_business_day('us'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 18), date.next_business_days(7, 'us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  1), date.previous_business_day(7, 'us'))
  end
  def test_2012_06_10_de()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 10)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 11), date.next_business_day('de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  8), date.previous_business_day('de'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 18), date.next_business_days(7, 'de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  1), date.previous_business_day(7, 'de'))
  end
  def test_2012_06_09_us()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 9)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 10), date.next_business_day('us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  8), date.previous_business_day('us'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 17), date.next_business_days(7, 'us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  1), date.previous_business_day(7, 'us'))
  end
  def test_2012_06_09_de()
    date = Date.new(2012, 6, 9)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 10), date.next_business_day('de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  8), date.previous_business_day('de'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06, 17), date.next_business_days(7, 'de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 06,  1), date.previous_business_day(7, 'de'))
  end
  def test_2012_12_24_us()
    date = Date.new(2012, 12, 24)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 26), date.next_business_day('us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 23), date.previous_business_day('us'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2013, 01,  3), date.next_business_days(7, 'us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 16), date.previous_business_day(7, 'us'))
  end
  def test_2012_12_24_de()
    date = Date.new(2012, 12, 24)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 27), date.next_business_day('de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 23), date.previous_business_day('de'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2013, 01,  4), date.next_business_days(7, 'de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 16), date.previous_business_day(7, 'de'))
  end
  def test_2012_12_26_us()
    date = Date.new(2012, 12, 26)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 27), date.next_business_day('us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 24), date.previous_business_day('us'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2013, 01,  4), date.next_business_days(7, 'us'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 17), date.previous_business_day(7, 'us'))
  end
  def test_2012_12_26_de()
    date = Date.new(2012, 12, 26)
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 27), date.next_business_day('de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 24), date.previous_business_day('de'))

    assert_equal( Date.new(2013, 01,  4), date.next_business_days(7, 'de'))
    assert_equal( Date.new(2012, 12, 17), date.previous_business_day(7, 'de'))
  end

end
```

See `test_2012_12_24_us()` and `date.next_business_days(7,...` You end in 2013, each holiday in the period is respected.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to calculate business days in the future starting from a Saturday or Sunday. 
1 business day after a Monday is the Tuesday, 1 business day from a Sunday should also be Tuesday - the starting weekend day should be ignored.
The following achieves this:

```
class Date

  def business_days_future(inc)
    date = skip_weekend
    inc.times do
      date = date + 1
      date = date.skip_weekend
    end
    date
  end

  # If date is a saturday or sunday, advance to the following monday
  def skip_weekend
    if wday == 0
      self + 1
    elsif wday == 6
      self + 2
    else
      self
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe this gem can be useful for you question

https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

This let you calculate hours and days of business from a date given

Answer (score 1):

Here's two examples for the number of working days between two dates:

1. http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1209

   - Also at: http://www.railsonwave.com/2007/1/30/calculate-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates
2. http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/93938#190402

Here's a Ruby holidays gem:

- http://github.com/alexdunae/holidays

  - Also at: http://code.dunae.ca/holidays/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster method that uses a simple calculation instead of iterating over the days.

```
class Time

  def shift_weekdays(num_weekdays)
    base = self

    # corner case: self falls on a Sat or Sun then treat like its the next Monday
    case self.wday
      when 0
        base = self + 1.day
      when 6
        base = self + 2.day
    end
    day_of_week = base.wday - 1 # Monday is 0

    weekends = (day_of_week + num_weekdays) / 5

    base + (weekends*2).days + num_weekdays.days
  end

end
```

The method is on class Time but can be used on Date class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is an old thread, but I just had to work this one out for myself and I was looking for a very short bit of code that was trivial to modify if a business had weird opening days (like "closed Sunday/Monday").

```
def next_business_day(from_day)
  workdays = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  test_day = from_day + 1.day
  return workdays.include?(test_day.wday) ? test_day : next_business_day(test_day)
end
```

I suppose it could be shortened again to something like this, but I think it becomes less obvious

```
def next_business_day(from_day)
  test_day = from_day + 1.day
  [1,2,3,4,5,6].include?(test_day.wday) ? test_day : next_business_day(test_day)
end
```

Comment: don't need return in last line

Comment: Thanks @piton4eg, shortened the short version a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use something like **yesterday = 1.days.ago** to get yesterday's date. Use **yesterday.strftime('%w')** to get the day of the week as a integer (0=Sunday, 6=Saturday). If yesterday is 0 (Sunday), then the previous day of the week would be 3.days.ago ... you get the idea.

And you can use **tomorrow = 1.days.since** to get tomorrow's date.

Answer (score 0):

this is implementation:

```
require 'business_time'

date = Time.now

next_workday(date)

private

def next_workday(date:)
  return date = date.next_weekday while date.workday?
end
```

Comment: Is there a `prev_weekday` too and does it work in exactly the same way?

Comment: I do not know, I used it this way only, I would have to test it

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use in my production scheduling script:

```
require 'date'
def shift_business_days(date, incr)
  date = Date.parse(date.to_s)
  incr.abs.times do
    date += (incr < 0 ? -1 : 1)
    while date.saturday? || date.sunday? do
      date += (incr < 0 ? -1 : 1)
    end
  end
  date
end
```

It takes a date and a positive or negative integer `incr` as arguments, and increments or decrements the date by `incr` days, skipping weekends. This has the added benefit of being able handle a Date/Time object or any date string that Date.parse can handle.
For example:

```
# (today is 2019-03-08)
shift_business_days(Time.now, 2)
##=> #<Date: 2019-03-12 ((2458555j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

shift_business_days('5/20', -10)
##=> #<Date: 2019-05-06 ((2458610j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on rails, You could create a config/initializers/date_time.rb

```
class DateTime
  def next_business_day
      # if its a friday saturday or sunday
    if self.day > 4

      # calculate the remaining days to add to the current day
      remaining_days = 7 - self.day + 1

      return remaining_days.days.from_now
    else

      # return tomorrow
      return self.tomorrow
    end
  end
end
```

usage:

```
a = DateTime.now
a.next_business_day
=> Mon, 08 Jun 2020 13:46:13 UTC +00:00
```