# Passing a previous date in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I want to create a link name as Previous date and Next date in my show action. Please suggest me that how should I pass the date in that . i.e. If one clicks on the previous link then the records are displayed of the previous day and vice versa.

How to pass the date in show action? Please guide.

P.S. :- I am using rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display date and pass as link parameter you can use either ruby code or jQuery .

Ruby : To get the date :
[How to calculate next, previous business day in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406617/how-to-calculate-next-previous-business-day-in-rails)

Put such function in your application helper . And call into you view and also pass as link parameter .

jQuery :

[Error creating a '< previous' and 'next >' (date) link for jQueryUI datepicker using setdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652948/error-creating-a-previous-and-next-date-link-for-jqueryui-datepicker-u)